# How to capture exception thrown by class definnition in python 2.7

Tags: python

I've go code like that:

```
class Foo:
    foo_const = function_which_throws_something()
```

How to capture such exception? Is it possible at all?

Comment: Actually in your case the exception is not raised by the class definition but by `function_which_throws_something()`. And from within your class definition it can be caught just like any other exception - `class` is an executable statement so you can have try/except, conditionals, loops, etc in the class statement's body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, execution of a function that can raise exceptions at definition time is a questionable design. It is of course allowed by Python language because a `def` statement is executable, but it does not improve readability.

My advice would be to execute the function later, after the class definition:

```
# definition
class Foo:
    foo_const = None       # default initialization in case of problem...

    @classmethod
    def init_foo(cls):
        cls.foo_const = function_which_throws_something()

# initialization
try:
    Foo.init_foo()
except:
    # process the exceptional condition
    ...
```

That way, the class is always constructed, you can simply process the exception and the const has a default value.

But if you want to produce shorter even if IMO less intelligible code, you could do:

```
try:
    class Foo:
        foo_const = function_which_throws_something()
except:
    class Foo:
        foo_const = None
    # further exception processing
    ...
```

Above code uses raw `except` to catch any exception which should be avoided, if only `SomeException` can be thrown, you should use:

```
try:
   ...
except SomeException:           # or except SomeException as e:
   ...
```

Comment: "a def expression is executable" => `def` is a statement not an expression - and this is totally unrelated since the exception is raised when _calling_ the function.

Comment: Also, dont use bare `except`s (unless you immediately reraise the very same exception).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: Of course you are right... Post edited.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Just wrap the class definition with try-except statements:

```
def some_func():
    raise Exception('some exception')

try:
    class X:
        y = some_func()
except Exception as e:
    print 'Got it!', e
```

Executing the code above prints:

```
Got it! some exception
```

Comment: The class won't even be constructed since you put the class definition inside the try block. You should try to minimize the code inside the try block as much as possible.

Comment: Correct, although the poster did not specify that they want to keep the class ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way, minimizing the code that can throw an exception inside the try - except block.

```
def throw_exception():
    raise Exception('exc')

class Foo(object):
    try:
        x = throw_exception()
    except Exception as exc:
        x = 'Exception was thrown: {}'.format(exc)

>>> Foo.x
'Exception was thrown: exc'
```

This code will always create the class, and the variable value depends on the function. If an exception happens, it captures it and edit the value.

Comment: Also, this is definitly NOT how to handle such a case - unless you can effectively __fix__ the problem at this point,  you should __log__ the exception and __reraise it__.  With your "solution", `Foo.x` is not properly initialized so the code will break elsewhere. If you can't properly recover from an exception, let it propagate, better to crash fast and loudly than to pretend everything's fine and either crash later (in totally unrelated places) or, even worse, produce incorrect results.

Comment: Thanks for your input :) I quickly validated it captures the exception without paying attention to the message. I fixed the code structure so now it actually does what it should. The reason for the function that just raise an exception is to illustrate. The OP didn't provide the function content, just the fact it may throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

In python everything except compilation to bytecode happens at runtime. IOW, `class` is an executable statement. When the interpreter reaches a `class` statement, it sets up a namespace, execute the whole `class` statement's body within that namespace, and uses all names defined in that namespace to use as class attributes. Then it calls `type()` with the class name, bases and the collected namespaces, and binds the newly created class object (instance of `type` or whatever custom metaclass) to the class name.

This means that you can execute any arbitrary code within the class statement - try/except, loops, conditionals, just whatever legit Python code, including, as in your example, calling a function. And actually in your case it's not the "class definition" that raises an exception but the function you call from within the `class` statement, so you can obviously wrap the call in a try/except block if it makes sense for you concrete problem (cf at the end of this answer).

Now for what happens if you don't handle the error at all: assuming your `class` statement is at the module's top level (not nested in a function), the exception will fire when the runtime executes the script or module containing the class definition. If the containing file is used as a module (=> imported from another place) - which is the most likely - this will happen on the first import of the module, be catched by the python runtime, and replaced by an ImportError, so you won't be able to properly handle the case from the importing code.

Obviously the best solution here is to avoid having any exception here, and if you cannot avoid it make sure you log the full exception (message & traceback) from within the class statement's body itself so you get a hint of why the import fails:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class Foo(object):
    try:
        myconst = some_func_that_raises()
    except Exception as e:
        logger.exception("failed to initialize Foo.my_const : %s", e)
        # let's not pretend otherwise : something failed and we cannot
        # fix it here
        raise
```

Now the real questions are: **why** does this function raise, can properly you recover from this exception (in a way that won't break the client code later I mean), and do you really need to call it *at this point* ? How to properly handle your case actually depends on those points